# split text into individual row python

Tags: python, loops, token

I'm struggling to convert an array into individual tokens.
Currently I used the following code, but am not getting to the exact output that I want. As I would like the numbers to be part of it too.

```
text = df.head(3)[['processed_arti', 'cluster']].values    // where df is a pandas dataframe

terms = [b for l in text for b in zip (l[0].split(" "))]
```

[image]

I've added another picture below showing a bit more detail of how the data looks. Read in a pandas dataframe.

[image]

I'd really appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide a MRE? stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `terms = [b for l in text for b in itertools.product(l[0].split(" "), l[1])]` ? `import itertools`

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide sample in python?

Comment: Thank you @RafaelValero your responses. 

I've added a few more details in the above question. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Epsi95 for your response. 

I get the following error when I try itertools - "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: @ALK, if you could please just copy and paste the code instead o pics that would be great. If you place pics them people have to write down themself the code you actually already have.

Comment: Thank you @RafaelValero for the recommendation and the help. I am sorted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get a list of lists contains your tuples:

```
[[(word, l[1]) for word in l[0].split('0')] for l in a] # a being your array.
```

Then you flatten the list of lists: see [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Or better, as Yevhen Kuzmovych suggested:

```
[(word, l[1]) for l in a for word in l[0].split('0')]
```

Note: Not verified. Typed on my mobile.

Comment: You can avoid flattening by removing the inside brackets and swapping the order of the `for` loops (like OP originally does and like I did in my answer)

Comment: Thanks @YevhenKuzmovych, I should have thought about it.

Comment: Thank you @YevhenKuzmovych for your help

Comment: Thank you @Tarik for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this what you need? You just need to add the number alongside your words:

```
terms = [(b, n) for l, n in text for b in l.split(" ")]
```